# T-SQL how to compare varchar alphanumeric value to int value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to query relational storage to return objects with a different value reported in a packet (`broadcast.FirmwareVersionReported`) compared to the value reported as last delivered (`device.firmwareid`).

- Column `broadcast.FirmwareVersionReported` is of type `varchar`
- Value example is `001`.
- Column `device.firmwareid` is of type `int`.
- Value example is `0001XX`.

**Testing**

I attempted to level the playing field by using `LEFT` to remove the last two characters from the column `firmware.softwareid` and used CAST to change both to a `VARCHAR` to allow the comparison. Its clear this approach is not correct however.

```
select 
    LEFT(CAST(firmware.softwareid as VARCHAR),4) AS softwareid, 
    CAST(broadcast.[FirmwareVersionReported] as VARCHAR) 
from 
    device
inner join 
    broadcast on broadcast.deviceid = device.deviceid
inner join 
    firmware on firmware.firmwareid = device.firmwareid
where
    softwareid <> [FirmwareVersionReported]
```

**Result**

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 7
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the not equal to operation.

**Tables**

Broadcast

```
[DeviceId] [int],
[FirmwareVersionReported] [varchar](10),
```

Firmware

```
[FirmwareID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
[SoftwareID] [varchar](10),
[PacketSoftwareID] [varchar](10),
```

Device

```
[DeviceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
[FirmwareID] [int],
```

**Question**

Looking for advice on how best to approach resolving this problem please.

Comment: You need to Collate before comparing

Comment: I think you should make all collations to be the same to avoid always converting collations for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting to char, convert to int for comparison:

```
select 
    LEFT(CAST(firmware.softwareid as VARCHAR),4) AS softwareid, 
    CAST(broadcast.[FirmwareVersionReported] as VARCHAR) 
from device
    inner join broadcast on broadcast.deviceid = device.deviceid
    inner join firmware on firmware.firmwareid = device.firmwareid
WHERE floor(cast(softwareid as int)/100) <> cast([FirmwareVersionReported] as int)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Cetin. With this approach I received the message: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0009XX' to data type int.".  This may be because I explained something incorrectly sorry.

Comment: Oh I got XX as 2 varying digits, then you can make it: cast(left(softwareid,4) as int) <> cast( ... )

Comment: Ah sorry , that was my fault. I should have explained XX part was alphabetical only characters.

Comment: Works perfectly using "cast(left(softwareid,4) as int) <>". Thank you. Marked as answered +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
select 
    LEFT(CAST(firmware.softwareid as VARCHAR),4) AS softwareid_mod, 
    CAST(broadcast.[FirmwareVersionReported] as VARCHAR) 
from device
    inner join broadcast on broadcast.deviceid = device.deviceid
    inner join firmware on firmware.firmwareid = device.firmwareid
WHERE LEFT(CAST(firmware.softwareid as VARCHAR),4) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT <> [FirmwareVersionReported] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: Thank you for the post Andrew. With this approach the results are:
0090  090 as a miss match. Infact this is not a miss match as the dropping the leading ZERO on 0090 would match the values.